# WPF: Anchor points don't work well sometimes

Tags: wpf, xaml

When I try to create a window using WPF (usually when the window is not re-sizable) this problem which has been shown in the below images happens. Although I can easily fix it by shrinking the inner frame a bit, I'm curious why it happens and in case it is a kind of Visual Studio form designer problem, why It's been happening for quite a long time.

[image]

Fixing the inner frame according to the designer view anchor points results in:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't position your controls absolutely. Remove the `Height`, `Width`, `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` from your Border so that it takes the entire window. Then set your margin to an uniform one (`Margin="10"`). It will look perfect for all window sizes.

If you don't want to edit the XAML file manually, you can clear the properties in the designer by clicking on the small square named "Default" near every property.